# Get exact match with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get exact match with LIKE.
Example; if .%query = 12;
I get match with 12, 121, 122, etc.etc.

```
"SELECT * FROM Bibliotek 
 WHERE (`Lopnr` LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER BY Lopnr ASC") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Just remove the % characters ;) or don't use LIKE at all, just the = character

Comment: Ah! That was easy!!! But hard for a newbie like myself! BIG THANKS!!!!

Comment: `mysqli_error()` requires a db connection as the argument. That won't show you anything when a query fails.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an answer:

```
"SELECT * FROM Bibliotek WHERE `Lopnr` LIKE '".$query."' ORDER BY Lopnr ASC"
```

OR

```
"SELECT * FROM Bibliotek WHERE `Lopnr` = '".$query."' ORDER BY Lopnr ASC"
```

If you want to improve your code (security wise) you should take a look at prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php